# MySQL LOAD_FILE and relative path - is there any GETCWD() function?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a script and I need to insert a content of binary file into the table cell. The function `LOAD_FILE` works with absolute path only. I need to update the script like this:

```
set @cwd = GETITSOMEHOW();
INSERT ... LOAD_FILE(CONCAT(@cwd, 'fileName.ext')), ...
```

Is there any *getClientWorkDir* function in MySQL?